# remove partition with win server 2008

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a dual boot notebook. Win 7 and Win server 2008.
Now I have a problem with disk space, so I plan to delete partition with win server 2008, so I can gain more disk space for win 7.
Haw I can do it in windows 7 ?
I try using EASEUS partition tool, but it not work.

any idea?

http://plixi.com/photos/original/63538882

My win server 2008 is in D partition (on win 7)
I want to remove it ( D )

Comment: Did EASEUS give any error messages? When errors exist, be careful with forcing the delete.

Comment: EASUS can't delete it because delete menu was disable. it's status is system, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to see if your boot partition is correctly set first. If not, deleting the partition can render your system unbootable.

If you want to do it in windows 7,

```
Control panel | Administrative tools | Computer management
```

Select `Disk Management` from the left and do whatever you want there.

Comment: this is my disk management screetshot, the Boot is in C, so is it ok to delete? how? http://c0013582.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/x2_3c986c2

Comment: broken link pal. add it to your question

Comment: Its a jpg file, and one lousy screenshot I might add.

Comment: sorry I edited the wrong post, its been corrected.

Comment: done :D

Answer (score 0):

If server 2008 was installed after W7, then use disk management to delete the partition, then reboot, if it does not boot, use a W7 DVD to do a startup repair.

Then all you need to do is remove the 2008 install from the bootloader.

Here is the screenshot he linked to, not much help, we need the entire shot of disk management.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, try also [Paragon Partition Manager Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/).